# Building a pole mount solution for Starlink flat high performance dish - not the standard high performance dish

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-analysis

I have a flat high performance dish that is mounted on my RV. But I also have the need to mount it higher at one of the long term locations I will be staying at. There are lots of solutions for mounting the standard high performance dish, but it's about 1/2 the size and weighs about 6 pounds. However the flat high performance weighs over 16 pounds on the Starlink wedge mount with the pole adapter, plus the weight of the cable itself.

Not knowing the grade of aluminum, is it realistic that interlocking s-wedged 4' sections of 20 gauge 2" aluminum could support the weight in normal conditions as well as moderate winds and at what height? Approximately 4-5' of the pole would be parallel mounted to the RV ladder. Ideally I'd like to try to get the dish 4 to 8 feet or maybe more to achieve the height needed to avoid obstructions. If this isn't viable, what material solution in the 2" range might be?